# update NSMutableArray based on index

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have NSMutableArray as below.

I have NSMutableArray data as below.

```
(
        {
        Id = 3;
        Name = Fahim;
    },
        {
        Id = 2;
        Name = milad;
    },
        {
        Id = 1;
        Name = Test;
    }
)
```

I want to change `milad` to `New Name`

Means I want to update the data of object at index 1.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: Are you getting index of object ?

Comment: yes, I have index of object as 1 (in my case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSMutableDictionary *miladData = [array[1] mutableCopy];
[miladData setObject:@"New Name" forKey:@"Name"];
[array replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:miladData];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:1] mutableCopy];
[tempDict setObject:@"New Name" forKey:@"Name"];
[yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:tempDict];
```

Answer (score 2):

If the objects in the array are mutable (an `NSMutableDictionary`, say), you can change the actual field, and you don't have to replace anything in the array:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:1];
[dict setObject:@"New Name" forKey:@"Name"];
```

If the objects in the array are immutable, you'll have to replace the object at the correct index:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"Id":@2, @"Name":@"New Name"};
[array replaceObejectAtIndex:1 withObject:dict];
```

You can also do this by creating a mutable copy (but in this case, unlike the first, you *have* to set it back into the array):

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[array objectAtIndex:1] mutableCopy];
[dict setObject:@"New Name" forKey:@"Name"];
[array replaceObejectAtIndex:1 withObject:dict];
```

The `Id` values in your dictionaries, incidentally, are not what we're using to locate things in your array. As you specified, we're using indexes. If you want to look up values based on those Id records, say so, because the code will be different then.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace your object once you get index of object.

```
[arrayOfData replaceObjectAtIndex:yourIndex withObject:yourObject];
```

Comment: what will be yourObject?

Comment: That will be object of your dict having Id,Name

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a mutable copy of the dictionary object at given index in your `NSMutableArray`. Modify the value for required key. Use the `NSMutableArray` API

```
[mutableArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:mutableCopiedObj];
```

Hope that helps!